# Groovy AST - Adding annotations at compilation

Tags: groovy

I'm trying to dynamicly crate an annotation that will dynamicaly add  an @XmlElement annotation to every field in a class using metaprogramming and AST. I'm having problems creating the annotations and applying them to the fields properly.

The code i have is formatted here: http://pastebin.com/60DTX5Ya

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement

@GroovyASTTransformation(phase = CompilePhase.CANONICALIZATION)
class WebserviceAnnotationModifier implements ASTTransformation {
@Override
void visit(ASTNode[] astNodes, SourceUnit sourceUnit) {

    if (!astNodes) return
    if (!astNodes[0] || !astNodes[1]) return
    if (!(astNodes[0] instanceof AnnotationNode)) return
    if (!(astNodes[1] instanceof ClassNode)) return
    ClassNode node = (ClassNode)astNodes[1]
    List fields = node.getFields()
    fields.each {FieldNode field ->
        field.addAnnotation(ClassHelper.make(new XmlElement.DEFAULT()));
    }
}
}

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
@Target([ElementType.TYPE])
@GroovyASTTransformationClass(classes =[WebserviceAnnotationModifier])
public @interface WebresourceAnnotation{}

@WebresourceAnnotation
class TestPerson{
    String name;
    String lastName;
    int Age
}
```

Am i approaching this all wrong? The reason i do this is i have a domain that is still in the making and i'd like to just go in and apply the annotation to all fields. Couldn't find any examples of annotations added during compilation. Is this not possible?

Comment: You're saying that you applying the annotation to domain. Is it Grails domain classes? I mean are you going to use your annotation in Grails environment?

Comment: Yes i will be using some JAXB XML annotations to generate a SOAP service. What i want is to have the WebresourceAnnotation annotation that will go through every field in the domain object and add a plain XmlElement annotation.

Answer (score 1):

Writing codes using Groovy AST Transformation alone does not work with the Grails reloading mechanism. Here's a proper way to implement AST transformation for a Grails app.

1. Your transformer class must extends [`AbstractGrailsArtefactTransformer`](http://grails.org/doc/latest/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/compiler/injection/AbstractGrailsArtefactTransformer.html).
2. Your transformer class must be annotated by `@AstTransformer`.
3. You class must be put under `org.codehaus.groovy.grails.compiler` or its sub-package. In my case I use `org.codehaus.groovy.grails.compiler.zk` and it's working fine.
4. Implement `shouldInject()` to match only classes you want, in this case domain classes.
5. Override `performInjection()` and write your codes there.
6. **Pack** your transformer and releated classes into a **.jar** file, or Grails compiler does not load it.

Comment: Thanks alot. I will take a look at it and see what i can figure out. I got so caught up in not being sure how to actually create an AnnotationNode.

Comment: No problem. Do not forget to accept it as the answer after you got your transformer working :)